# Neo4J - Building Graph

Tags: graph, neo4j

not sure this is the best forum to ask this question. Please apologize if it is not the case and tell me where I can redirect this question before to vote me.

I'd like to know if my approach to build my graph is the most appropriate one or not, by taking into account the kind of query i expect to perform on it.

So, I am building on a weekly basis a graph on Neo4J from tweets taken from the Stream API and for a specific list of hashtags. The list of hashtags grows every week.

This is a research project, so that I'll do this activity only for about two months.

I decided to model my graph that way:

- Nodes:

  - user that emitted the tweet
  - user mentioned in the tweet
  - original user in case of retweet
- Edges:

  - retweeted
  - mentioned

I'd like to extract the subgraph,i.e. all nodes and edges, that are related to a specified tag, from the main built graph.

My question is thus:

A. Is it better to add a tag attribute to all users and edges ?

or

B. Is it better to define a new node, for each tag, and then create edges between tags and users ?
Some sort of relationship :  -  is related

Then, what would be the recommended way to query the graph db...
So for exampple, if the second solution B. is recommended, should and can the query being executed as a two step query :

- step 1: all nodes that has the relationship  is related to
- step2: all nodes and edges related to the nodes extracted in the first step query.

Answer (score 1):

I think it makes sense to have `Tag` nodes with relationship from `Tweet` to the `Tag` nodes that the tweet uses: `(Tweet)-[:TAGS]->(Hashtag)`

You might want to look at this [Twitter demo app](http://network.graphdemos.com/) that pulls Twitter data into Neo4j and has some [example queries](http://network.graphdemos.com/#queries) you might find interesting. There is a blog post [here](http://neo4j.com/blog/graph-your-network-neo4j-docker-image/) that discusses how this web app was built.

You also might be interested in the [Neo4j Slack group](http://neo4j.com/slack), specifically the #help-modeling channel for data modeling discussion / issues.